# Can you use the Kinect for Xbox for Kinect Fusion?

Tags: windows, kinect, xbox

I have a Kinect for Xbox that I would like to use for Kinect Fusion, but it doesn't recognize the sensor when it is plugged in. Would I need a Kinect for Windows to be able to use Kinect Fusion?

Comment: It works with the Kinect SDK for Windows though...

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young - That is not correct.  The Kinect for Xbox works just fine on Windows with the Kinect SDK.  Microsoft has put restrictions on what can be done with the hardware but the majority of functionality is available.

Comment: @9byte - Do other example programs provided with the SDK recognize your sensor and behave as expected?

Comment: @EvilClosetMonkey Thanks for the correction. I'll nuke my comment.

Answer (score 2):

There is no problem running Kinect fusion with a Kinect for XBox, As far as I know theonly option that doesn't work on XBox version is near mode, but that's not required for fusion.

In case your card does not support DirectX11 you will not be able to use hardware acceleration tho, so in c# you need to use the following flag :

```
ReconstructionProcessor ProcessorType = ReconstructionProcessor.Cpu;
```

instead of

```
ReconstructionProcessor ProcessorType = ReconstructionProcessor.Amp;
```

Also make sure to copy binaries in the same folder as your executable (eg: KinectFusion180_32.dll or 64 bits version to your convenience).

That's more or less it, it just works )